# Redirecting and getting "Leaving this page" alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, notifications, alert

Is it possible to suppress the "Leave this page" alert when redirecting to another page?

[image]

I am using the jQuery notification popup [Apprise v2](http://thrivingkings.com/read/Apprise-v2-The-new-and-improved-attractive-alert-alternative-for-jQuery) and once i click on the "OK" button on the popup box this is the code i execute:

```
if (window.location.protocol != "https:") {
    //window.location.href ="https://" + location.hostname + '/thank-you';
    window.location.replace("https://" + location.hostname + '/thank-you');                                                 
} else {            
    //window.location.href ='/thank-you';
    window.location.replace("/thank-you");
}
```

As you see above, I've tried both **window.location.href** and **window.location.replace** but they give the same alert box it seems.

Comment: if the alert comes from javascript via an `onbeforeunload` handler, then you can suppress it. if it is coming from the browser, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait, do you mean:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Comment: You got it, roasted. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: doesn't work for me, doing this and I still get the popup

Comment: it was because there was another `onbeforeunload` my bad